# Order statistics: What's the probability that all three components will fail within 2 years of each other?

Tags: order-statistics

Suppose an instrument has three independent parts, all of whose lifetimes (in years) are modeled by an exponential pdf which is
$f_Y(y)=e^{-y}, y>0. $ What's the probability that all three parts will fail within two years of one another?

I understand how to find the cdf (it would be $ F_Y(y)=1-e^{-y} $). I also know the formula to find the pdf of the $i^{th}$ order statistic is as follows: $f^{'}_{Y_i}(y)=\frac{n!}{(i-1)!(n-i)!}[F_Y(y)]^{i-1}[1-F_Y(y)]^{n-i}f_Y(y)  $ for $ 1 \le i \le n.$

However I'm having trouble understanding how to incorporate the fact that they would all fail within two years of each other $(0 \le y \le 2?)$; how can this incorporated?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint for a shortcut: exponentially distributed random variables have the memorylessness property

Comment: Thank you for the shortcut:) in this case I guess the probability that all three parts fail within 2 years of each other would be the same as the probability one part failing within two years, right?

Comment: In this case that would be great but I would still love to know how to solve this without knowing that fact :)

Comment: The answer to this question is the same as the probability that two out of two fail in two years starting from $0$

Comment: Thank you! Why is this the case? Wouldn't all three parts have to be considered?

Comment: It is because after the first fails there will be two left to fail, plus the memorylessness property

Comment: Oh okay, thank you! So here, could I calculate the probability the first part fails in two years, then multiply by the probability the second part fails in two years, in order to get the probability all three fail within 2 years of each other?

Answer (score 1):

My earlier comments gave the memoryless property of the exponential distribution as a short cut.

If you want the long and more general way of doing this for $n$ i.i.d. continuous non-negative random variables each with density $f(x)$ and with cumulative distribution function $F(x)$, you could try the following steps:

- The probability none have failed by time $t\gt 0$ is $(1-F(t))^n$
- So the probability at least one has failed by time $t$ is $G(t) = 1-(1-F(t))^n$
- So the density function for the time of the first failure is $g(x) = G'(t) = n f(t) (1 - F(t))^{n-1} $
- Given that the first to fail has failed at time $t$, the probability a particular other one has failed by time $s+t$ with $s\gt 0$ is $\frac{F(s+t)-F(t)}{1-F(t)}$
- So given that the first to fail has failed at time $t$, the probability the other $n-1$ have failed by time $s+t$ with $s\gt 0$ is $\left(\frac{F(s+t)-F(t)}{1-F(t)}\right)^{n-1}$
- So the overall probability that all three fail within time $s$ of each other is $$\int\limits_{t=0}^\infty g(t) \left(\frac{F(s+t)-F(t)}{1-F(t)}\right)^{n-1} \, dt = \int\limits_{t=0}^\infty n\, f(t)\, \left({F(s+t)-F(t)}\right)^{n-1} \, dt$$
- Here $s=2$ and $n=3$

Comment: Hi Henry, thank you for this! This is super clear and helpful. I understand how this is derived until the third step;; in the fourth bullet, where did this equation come from? Why is it true? Thank you,

Comment: @Sarina: $1-F(t)$ is the probability of it not failing by time $t$, while $F(s+t)-F(t)$  is the probability of it not failing by time $t$ but failing by time $s+t$, so $\dfrac{F(s+t)-F(t)}{1-F(t)}$ is the conditional probability of it failing by time $s+t$ given that it has not failed by time $t$

Comment: @Sarina - no, since the first failure time of $t$ can be any positive value